# C# Linq use Where with IsNull() Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int?'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am in the process of converting an old classic asp site to .NET MVC 5, Entity Framework 6.

I am stuck on a linq query that I cannot figure out.
Here is my original SQL query:

```
@"SELECT DISTINCT AC.id, AC.name, ISNULL(AC.[order], 999) 
        FROM tbl12AuditCategories AC 
        INNER JOIN tbl12AuditQuestions AQ ON AC.id = AQ.new_categoryId 
        WHERE AQ.include = 1 AND AC.include = 1 AND ISNULL(AC.AuditQuestionGroupId, '0') = ? 
        ORDER BY ISNULL(AC.[order], 999), AC.name";
```

I would pass in a value to the ISNULL(AC.AuditQuestionGroupId, '0') = ?. Now with Linq I can just pass the value in easily.

```
 PracticeConductViewModel pcvm = new PracticeConductViewModel();
            pcvm.Categories = (from x in _repository.GetAll<ReviewCategory>()
                               join y in _repository.GetAll<ReviewQuestion>()
                                on x.id equals y.CategoryId
                               orderby x.order == null ? 999 : x.order, x.name
                              where x.include == true && y.include == true && (x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0)
                              select x).ToList();
```

My problem is this line:
where x.include == true && y.include == true && (x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0)

I get the error:

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int?'
```

I understand what it is telling me, but I can't figure out how to correctly get the ISNULL(..) function converted from the SQL.

Comment: You are missing the comparison that you have in your SQL query.

Comment: It is there: `ISNULL(AC.AuditQuestionGroupId, '0') = ?`

Comment: Yes, that's in the SQL query but not in the LINQ query, and that is the cause of your problem, as @MikeParkhill points out in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) resolves to a nullable int which obviously doesn't belong as part of a boolean condition.

Did you mean something like:

```
where x.include == true && y.include == true
   && ((x.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? x.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) ==  this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId)
```

Comment: Some advertisement: Using the null-coalescing Operator makes your query shorter (and is pretty useful converting ISNULL's from SQL): `[...] && ((x.AuditQuestionGroupId ?? 0) ==  this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId)`