# Why I get error message Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get following error message when I want to pass `UserID` to my Controller and limited access to `Ticket`
So every User can see only their own ticket, but as `Admin` can see all of the ticket.

```
    var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: x => isAdministrator || x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id, includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
```

So far what I try is something like this :

**Method 1**

```
   var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: x => isAdministrator || x.UserId = account.FirstOrDefault().Id, includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
```

**Method 2**

```
   var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: (x => isAdministrator || x.UserId = account.FirstOrDefault().Id), includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
```

**Method 3** (When I use something like this I get x as unexsisting context)

```
The name 'x' does not exist in the current context       

  var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: (x => isAdministrator) || (x.UserId = account.FirstOrDefault().Id), includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
```

I have no idea where I made mistake and what I made wrong but whatever I try I get always error message.
I check a couple of post here

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542133/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-and-int-using-asp)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153930/c-sharp-linq-use-where-with-isnull-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands)

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

**UPDATE**

Here is my full code of this function

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
            var account = _unitOfwork.ApplicationUser.GetFirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(username));
            var isAdministrator = User.IsInRole("Admin");
            var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: x => x.isAdministrator || x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id, includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
            return Json(new { data = obj });
        }
```

Comment: Dit you try parenthesis? `isAdministrator || (x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id)`

Comment: He tried, but in the shown example he used `=` instead of  `==`

Comment: Do you notice that `account.FirstOrDefault()` could return the default, which might be `null`?

Comment: I have to ask, what is passing the user id to the controller? If that is coming from a browser (or any client-controller user agent) you have to realize anyone could forge any user id they want.

Comment: You describe 3 ways you tried. But in all 3 you do an assignment with = operator, not a comparison with ==. So I'm a bit confused, because in your initial line of code you actually do the comparison with ==. Can you give more information about that?

Comment: I try also as `==` but doesn't work

Comment: `var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: (x => isAdministrator) || (x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id), includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");`

Comment: @UnKnowUser don't include the `(x =>` within the parenthesis

Comment: Yes, i also try this but doesn't work. I get error message 
`The name 'x' does not exist in the current context `

Comment: Because - to the best ability of the compiler to parse your input - you are asking it to compare a 'bool' and a 'int' using the '||' operator. My general rule is: "The only 'price' for squeezing a lot of code into a single line, is having a heck of a time debugging the stuff!" If you can not debug it, split it over multiple lines, using temporary variables. Never be worried about the performance impact - between the JIT and the Compiler optimsiations, underused variables will be cut in release builds.

Comment: You should give more context, because people need to guess your structures. It will not help..

Comment: I Update my question. Look at Update section. Sorry for that. I forget to include other properties

Comment: Are you sure about that `x.isAdministrator`, as in the line above you also create a local variable `isAdministrator` that you are now ignoring. You may want to remove that `x.`

Comment: I try to remove `x` but nothing happened. Again same error message.

Comment: Also I try to remove `paranthesis`

Comment: A Jeroen mentioned, did you try `filter: x => isAdministrator || (x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id)`  (using the local isAdministrator variable, a `==` for equality comparison and ( ) around the second part only)?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes, I try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you methods you have used `=` instead of `==`, unlike `==` which is a comparison and has a boolean result `=` is assigning and its value is determined on the variable type which is `int` in your case (`x.UserId`). and `||` can only be applied to boolean type:

```
(x => isAdministrator) || (x.UserId = account.FirstOrDefault().Id)
//-------boolean-------    ---int---
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work ! I update my question. Look at `Update` section

Comment: I have alredy this this solution and It throw error message as 
`The name 'x' does not exist in the current context `

Answer (score 0):

Taking on from your initial code (and assuming isAdministrator is a bool)

```
var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(filter: x => x.isAdministrator || x.UserId == account.FirstOrDefault().Id, includeProperties: "TicketType,ApplicationUser");
```